# Is it possible to pass properties between MSBuild projects?

Tags: msbuild

Is it possible to pass a property from one msbuild project to another? So in one .proj file there is a property with PropertyName="Foo" (for example). Can we access this from another .proj file i.e. use "$(Foo)" in the other msbuild project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is to pass properties as you call the next script, e.g.

```
<MSBuild Projects="another.proj" Properties="PropertyName=$(Foo)" />
```

Answer (score 4):

By using the [Import element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/92x05xfs.aspx) in the file where you want to use the property.

```
<Import Project="ProjectPath"/>
```

Comment: In that case there would be a cross reference between scripts. Is it ok?

Comment: How is the evaluation order determined? Imported project's properties and item groups are processed first? ItemGroups and properties in the current file are proecssed first?

Comment: I think the evaluation is determined by the order. If you import in the beginning imported project properties and items will be processed first. If you import in the end, imported project properties and items will be processed last.
That's the reason why in csproj import of "Microsoft.CSharp.targets" is done last, that's way you can set the value in the csproj.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **$(MSBuildArguments)** variable. I know that it works in TFS but I am not sure if it works in command prompt.